# tensorflow-lite tf.lite.Interpreter set_tensor failing to properly recognize uint8 input tensors

Tags: keras, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite, quantization

I have a working `.tflite` model (which takes 180x180 float greyscale image) as input, and returns 6 float sigmoid outputs. All works as-expected yielding expected results with test images.

I am trying to quantize `.tflite` model to `uint8`. Notice I am setting the input and output types to `unit8` (edited for brevity):

```
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
converter.representative_dataset = representative_dataset_gen
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS_INT8]
converter.inference_input_type = tf.uint8
converter.inference_output_type = tf.uint8
```

When I try to run inference on it with the following code (brevity):

```
  print ("IMAGE_ARRAY type",img_array.dtype)
  interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path="bkgmodel_quant.tflite")
  interpreter.resize_tensor_input(0, [1, 180, 180, 1])
  interpreter.allocate_tensors()
  print ("INPUT TENSOR",interpreter.get_input_details())
  input = interpreter.tensor(interpreter.get_input_details()[0]["index"])
  output = interpreter.tensor(interpreter.get_output_details()[0]["index"])
  interpreter.set_tensor(0, img_array)
```

When I run I get the following error:

`ValueError: Cannot set tensor: Got value of type UINT8 but expected type INT8 for input 0, name: input_2_int8`

When I look at the types of the image data and input tensors, they inded *are* `uint8`:

```
IMAGE_ARRAY type uint8
INPUT TENSOR [{'name': 'input_2', 'index': 22, 'shape': array([  1, 180, 180,   1], dtype=int32), 'shape_signature': array([ -1, 180, 180,   1], dtype=int32), 'dtype': <class 'numpy.uint8'>, 'quantization': (1.0, 0), 'quantization_parameters': {'scales': array([1.], dtype=float32), 'zero_points': array([0], dtype=int32), 'quantized_dimension': 0}, 'sparsity_parameters': {}}]
```

(look only at `dtype` in the input tensor, I assume).

So - indeed, the input tensor *should* be a uint8, and the image *is* a uint8 - yet I get this error.

As an experiment - I tried changing *only* my inference code to set the image data to `int8`. When I do, the error goes away and the inference runs, *however* my models predictions are all wrong.

(It is notable that the output values all add up to *almost* 256. I am assuming this means that the model is working correctly and yielding valid data - and I am also assuming that 8-bit sigmoids are expected to have a bit of a roundoff error where they don't add up to exactly 256??)

If I am doing something wrong, or is this a bug in Tensorflow-lite??

Comment: There's a line in the [Post Training Quantization](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/post_training_integer_quant#convert_using_integer-only_quantization) docs : *Now you have an integer quantized model that uses integer data for the model's input and output tensors, so it's compatible with integer-only hardware such as the Edge TPU.* - Probably you aren't using that *integer-only hardware*

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal Hmmm - I upgraded from TF 2.3 to 2.5 and the problem went away - BUT - I also switched from an Intel Atom to an NVIDIA Jetson in the process - so - two variables. SO it COULD be hardware- but even the buggy model was okay with going int8 - just not uint8...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I upgraded from Tensorflow 2.3 to 2.5, and the problem appears to have been fixed.